# beautifulsoup to get both link and link text inside an HTML table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am dealing with HTML table data consisting of two fields: First, a field that holds a hyperlinked text string, and second, one that holds a date string.  I need the two to be extracted and remain associated.

I am catching the rows in the following fashion (found from another SO question):

```
pg = s.get(url).text  # s = requests Session object
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg, 'html.parser')

files = [[
    [td for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    for tr in table.find_all('tr')]
    for table in soup.find_all('table')]
```

iterating over `files[0]` yields rows that have dynamic classes because the HTML was published from Microsoft Excel.  So I can't depend on class names.  But the location of elements are stable.  The rows look like this:

```
[<td class="excel auto tag" height="16" style="height:12.0pt;border-top:none"><a href="subfolder/north_america-latest.shp.zip"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Courier New", monospace;mso-font-charset:0'>north_america-latest.shp.zip</span></a></td>, <td class="another auto tag" style="border-top:none;border-left:none">2023-01-01</td>]
```

Broken up, for easier reading:

```
[
  <td class="excel auto tag" height="16" style="height:12.0pt;border-top:none">
    <a href="subfolder/north_america-latest.shp.zip">
      <span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Courier New", monospace;mso-font-charset:0'>
        north_america-latest.shp.zip
      </span>
    </a>
  </td>, 
  <td class="another auto tag" style="border-top:none;border-left:none">
    2023-01-01
  </td>
]
```

Using the `.get_text()` method with `td` I can get the string literal of the link, as well as the date in one go, but once I have the `td` object, how do I go about obtaining the following three elements?

```
"subfolder/north_america-latest.shp.zip"  # the link
"north_america-latest.shp.zip"  # the name
"2023-01-01"  # the date
```

Comment: Can you confirm the url of the page in question, is it publicly available? Failing that, can you provide the *full* HTML of the page in question, using a service like pastebin/similar?

Comment: Sorry, it's on an intranet.  However, as stated I can access the table rows without issue.  I could also just brute force it and grab the links with regex but I wanted to find out if there was anything more elegant built into beautifulsoup.

Comment: You should not parse html with regex. Next, it's not difficult to get those attributes from `<td>` tag. However, your issue  (which sounds close to an XY Problem) is difficult to debug, without enough information - like page HTML.

Comment: No, it's not an XY problem, and here's a simpler phrasing:  Given the row above, how would you go about extracting both the `href` and the text from it?  Thanks.

Comment: That row is not a valid list, and your main issue is with extracting the elements initially. Sorry, I cannot debug this without the actual html (before any gymnastics resulting in lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you call 'row' is actually a string, here is how you would get those bits of information:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

my_list = '''[<td class="excel auto tag" height="16" style="height:12.0pt;border-top:none"><a href="subfolder/north_america-latest.shp.zip"><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Courier New", monospace;mso-font-charset:0'>north_america-latest.shp.zip</span></a></td>, <td class="another auto tag" style="border-top:none;border-left:none">2023-01-01</td>]'''
soup = bs(my_list, 'html.parser')

link = soup.select_one('td a').get('href')
text = soup.select_one('td a').get_text()
date = soup.select('td')[1].get_text()
print('link:', link)
print('text:', text)
print('date:', date)
```

Result in terminal:

```
link: subfolder/north_america-latest.shp.zip
text: north_america-latest.shp.zip
date: 2023-01-01
```

I'm not particularly convinced this is the actual key to your conundrum: surely there is a better way of getting the information you're after, beside that list comprehension you're using. As stated in comments, without the actual page HTML, truly debugging this is next to impossible.

Comment: This is very helpful and yes, you're correct it is a string (what I erroneously posted was the terminal output - sorry).  This is just part of a hack script that is intended to run as a cron and keep our OpenStreetMap data holdings up-to-date.  It gets the job done!  Thanks!